# Como trazer apenas o registros que nao tem associação na segunda tabela?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Pessoal tenho uma query que retorna o numero de telefones cadastrados em cada estado,pais e traz tambem o numero de clientes que nao tem telefone cadastrado em cada estado,pais mas gostaria que trazer apenas esses clientes que nao tem telefone cadastrado...a query eh essa:

```
SELECT s.cState,co.cCountry ,ISNULL(cTelephoneType,'NONE') AS 'Tipo Telefone', COUNT(*) AS 'TOTAL' FROM Customer c 
LEFT JOIN CustomerTelephone ct  on c.nIDCustomer = ct.nIDCustomer JOIN State s on
c.nIDState = s.nIDState JOIN Country co on co.nIDCountry = s.nIDCountry LEFT JOIN TelephoneType tt on tt.nIDTelephoneType = ct.nIDTelephoneType 
GROUP BY s.cState,co.cCountry,cTelephoneType
```

e o resultado esse por enquanto:

```
Florida United States   NONE    16
Nevada  United States   NONE    7
Nevada  United States   Cell Phone  7
Nevada  United States   Home    2
Nevada  United States   Work    1
Roma    Italia  NONE    96
Roma    Italia  Cell Phone  28
Roma    Italia  Home    4
Roma    Italia  Work    3
Rosário Argentina   NONE    7
São Paulo   Brazil  NONE    7
Yucatán Mexico  NONE    8
```

Queria que só aparecesse os registros 'NONE'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algo assim?

```
SELECT s.cState,co.cCountry, ISNULL(c.TelephoneType,'NONE') AS 'Tipo Telefone', 
    COUNT(*) AS 'TOTAL' 
FROM Customer c 
-- LEFT JOIN CustomerTelephone ct on c.nIDCustomer = ct.nIDCustomer 
JOIN State s on c.nIDState = s.nIDState 
JOIN Country co on co.nIDCountry = s.nIDCountry 
-- LEFT JOIN TelephoneType tt on tt.nIDTelephoneType = ct.nIDTelephoneType 
GROUP BY s.cState,co.cCountry,c.TelephoneType
WHERE c.TelephoneType is null;
```

---

EDIT

Conforme pedido por comentário:

```
SELECT s.cState,co.cCountry, ISNULL(c.TelephoneType,'NONE') AS 'Tipo Telefone', 
    COUNT(*) AS 'TOTAL' 
FROM Customer c 
-- LEFT JOIN CustomerTelephone ct on c.nIDCustomer = ct.nIDCustomer 
JOIN State s on c.nIDState = s.nIDState 
JOIN Country co on co.nIDCountry = s.nIDCountry 
-- LEFT JOIN TelephoneType tt on tt.nIDTelephoneType = ct.nIDTelephoneType 
GROUP BY s.cState,co.cCountry,c.TelephoneType
WHERE c.TelephoneType is null;

UNION

SELECT s.cState,co.cCountry, c.TelephoneType AS 'Tipo Telefone', 
    COUNT(*) AS 'TOTAL' 
FROM Customer c 
INNER JOIN CustomerTelephone ct on c.nIDCustomer = ct.nIDCustomer 
INNER JOIN TelephoneType tt on tt.nIDTelephoneType = ct.nIDTelephoneType 
INNER JOIN State s on c.nIDState = s.nIDState 
INNER JOIN Country co on co.nIDCountry = s.nIDCountry 
GROUP BY s.cState, co.cCountry, c.TelephoneType
WHERE c.TelephoneType is not null;
```

Comment: É exatamente isso...valeu !

Comment: Cigano agora eu preciso de uma query usando o UNION com essa query que traz os clientes sem telefone e com uma outra que traz o numero de telefones cadastrados por estado,pais sem usar LEFT JOIN tem ideia como ? o resultado seria esse mesmo de cima...

Comment: @Daniel Você fala, só unir o resultado?

Comment: é quero unir o resultado da query que traz os estados e pais com telefone cadastrado com a segunda query essa que vc me ajudou...porem nao posso usar LEFT JOIN...sabe como ?

Comment: @Daniel Editei a resposta.

Comment: beleza vo testa aqui

Comment: Obrigado novamente Cigano é isso mesmo

Comment: o Cigano na real eu precisaria de um outro jeito...eu tivi que descomentar os LEFT JOINS ali pra traze o resultado que eu esperava...eu precisava desse resultado sem usar LEFT JOIN

Comment: @Daniel Por que?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17357/discussion-between-daniel-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).